# Is there a better way to group a log on minutes?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following that selects from a log and groups down to minute (excluding seconds and milisec):

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]) AS YEAR, DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) AS MONTH,
       DATEPART(DAY, [Date]) AS DAY, DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]) AS HOUR,
       DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) AS MIN, COUNT(*) AS COUNT

FROM [database].[dbo].[errorlog]

GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]), DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), DATEPART(DAY, [Date]),
         DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]), DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date])

ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]) DESC, DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) DESC,
         DATEPART(DAY, [Date]) DESC, DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]) DESC,
         DATEPART(MINUTE, [Date]) DESC;
```

But as you can see thats a lot of fuzz just for getting a count, so I wonder if there is a better way to group it so I get grouped down to minutes in respect to year, month, day and hour?

Comment: Don't forget to mention which SQL Database and version you are using.

Comment: Im using MSSQL 2008 R2

Comment: Can you tell us what is the data type for your [Date] column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should would work:

```
select CAST([Date] AS smalldatetime) as time_stamp, count(*) as count
FROM [database].[dbo].[errorlog]
group by CAST([Date] AS smalldatetime)
order by CAST([Date] AS smalldatetime) desc;
```

Update after comments on this answer:

```
select dateadd(second,-datepart(ss,[Date]),[Date]) as time_stamp, count(*) as count
FROM [database].[dbo].[errorlog]
group by dateadd(second,-datepart(ss,[Date]),[Date]) 
order by dateadd(second,-datepart(ss,[Date]),[Date]) desc ;
```

The first solution rounds up the timestamp to the nearest minute. I realised that this is not exactly what the OP wanted.
So, the second solution just substracts the `seconds` part from the timestamp and leaves the timestamp with seconds as `zero`(Assuming [Date] does not have fractional seconds)

Comment: They don't want to ignore time completely - just the seconds and millis.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm not following your comment. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418(v=sql.100).aspx says smalldatetime "Defines a date that is combined with a time of day. The time is based on a 24-hour day, with seconds always zero (:00) and without fractional seconds."

Comment: It rounds if awkwardly 12:35:29.999 -> 12:36, 12:35:29.000 -> 12:35, I think he wants all 12:35:xx.xxx -> 12.35

Comment: @JanneMatikainen: I think the rounding is actually consistent. The rounding is happening right to left.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen: I think the rounding is actually consistent. The rounding is happening right to left.12:35:29.999 --> fractional seconds get rounded up to the next second, this in turn pushes the second part to 30 and since this is the threshold to round up to the next minute, 12:35:29.999 --> gets rounded to 12:36:00. However, 12:35:29.000 -->gets rounded to 12:35 because a. there is no fractional seconds involved, so it goes and checks the seconds part. As it is less than 30 12:35:29.000 -->gets rounded to 12:35:00.

Comment: 12:35:29.999 is a bad example (if that's going in a `datetime` column rather than `datetime2`) since `.999` is an invalid milliseconds value for such a column. `select CAST(CAST('2013-10-02T12:35:29.997' as datetime) as smalldatetime)` returns 12:35:00.

Comment: Yes, but i think he wants all log items in 12.35.00 - 12.35.99 to same group, not 12.34:30 - 12.35:29.99?

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,'20010101',[Date]),'20010101')
```

Should round all `Date` column values down to the nearest minute. So:

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,'20010101',[Date]),'20010101'),
     COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM [database].[dbo].[errorlog]
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,'20010101',[Date]),'20010101')
ORDER BY DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,'20010101',[Date]),'20010101') DESC;
```

(You could move this expression into a subquery if you want to further reduce the repetition)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get

```
declare @now datetime
set @now = GETDATE()

select dateadd(minute, mm, @now) as date, c from (
  select DATEDIFF(minute, @now, [Date]) as mm, COUNT(1) as c
  from [database].[dbo].[errorlog]
  group by DATEDIFF(minute, @now, [Date])
) t
```